# Best way to identify objects using Calabash on iOS

Tags: ios, automated-tests, calabash, pageobjects

I know calabash comes with the included irb functionality that allows you to query objects on the page.  However, this seems quite cumbersome.

Appium comes with a fantastic out of the box app that allows you to easily identify the details of objects on the page.

Does anyone know of an equivalent tool that can be used with Calabash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Calabash 0.19.0 added several console methods to help with discovering elements in an app's view hierarchy.

```
   ids => List all the visible accessibility ids.
labels => List all the visible accessibility labels.
  text => List all the visible texts.
 marks => List all the visible marks.
  tree => The app's visible view hierarchy.
 flash => flash(<query>); Disco effect for views matching <query>
```

[Reveal](http://revealapp.com/) is good option.

Calabash 2.0 has the `tree` [console command](https://github.com/calabash/calabash/blob/develop/lib/calabash/console_helpers.rb#L10) which could be ported to Calabash iOS 0.x.

There are also these useful methods in [briar/irbrc](https://github.com/jmoody/briar/blob/develop/lib/briar/irbrc.rb#L78)

Answer (score -1):

You can use Ruby to pull all the elements. I am assuming you are using mac and here is what you need to perform step by step:

1. gem install calabash-android
2. make a folder and place your apk in it.
3. go to your folder, calabash-android gen
4. calabash-android resign appName.apk
5. calabash-android build appName.apk
6. calabash-android run appName.apk
7. calabash-android console appname.apk
8. query("Webview css='button’) - this will return you all the buttons. And you can modify it according to your requirements.

Comment: Sorry - was actually meaning on iOS - I have updated the question title to make it clearer

Comment: you get the idea how it works so now u can make it work same on iOS too